# Graph of different objects (implementing a similar interface) in a relational database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, relational-database

So I was pondering about certain problem involving serialization of objects to relational databases.

Let's say you have N different objects, all implementing a certain interface (a directed graph interface for that matter. they provide methods such as getIncomingNodes() , getOutgoingNodes()).

If each such object has a corresponding table in a relational database,
What's the best practice of serializing such a directed graph to a relational database?

Assuming N is small, (in my case, N=3) I decomposed all possible links to be contained in a separate table.
For example, A table of links directed from object x to y will be similar to:

```
tbl_links_X_Y {
int X_id
int Y_id
}
```

Problem is , you get N^2 such tables - not very efficient, and could prove difficult to extend in the future to N+1 objects.

Is there any pattern that solves that issue?  (even if it does not involve relational databases, I would be happy to hear...)

Thanks!o

Comment: Your question is tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:postgresql].  Which are you using?

Comment: I haven't really committed to any framework. I guess I'll use the one that can solve my problem most efficiently :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So recently I ran into a NoSQL framework calls [OrientDB](http://orientdb.org/)
 That DB engine handles this issue exactly.
It is a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) that has the ability to perform SQL queries and lazy-load object (such as neighboring vertices) that are pointed by another object.

One thing that remains is to compare the performance of this framework to that of a traditional SQL database. (Of course, I'll have to take into account the time it would take for constructing the objects from the raw responses to the query in a traditional SQL database.. )

Once I'll have the results of this comparison i'll post them here.

Comment: Did you get a chance to make this comparison? In your original question,you had asked about mapping a graph structure to a relational model. One thing that should not be overlooked /underestimated is that riding on  the strengths of a battle-hardened,well-tested Relational DB like Postgres,and the responsiveness of the associated forums/mailing lists. It's not just the performance-if you are ever debugging corrupted data.. you don't want to find a dead mailing list and that that main guys who developed this, have moved on!!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store the class of the objects (table names) in the connection table as well.

```
tbl_links_X_Y {
int X_id
int Y_id
enum {user, customer, product} X_type
enum {user, customer, product} Y_type
}
```

They you would just include this in the where or join clause.

I guess this would not be a strictly relational database, since you can't (?) use/enforce foreign key constraints.

Comment: Would be problematic when you try joins as well. I guess that if you have N different objects, and you want to get all the neighbors of some object, there is no refuge. You have to make O(N) queries... I think the edge-list approach works best. Perhaps with some optimizations it won't be so bad...

Answer (score 0):

You could also  "force" your graph to follow the relational model : ie

Table Graph { 
integer vertexid,
varchar  edgelist
}

edgelist could be made a delimiter based string: For instance {2,10},{3,12},{4,13} etc  where entries are {incident vertex,weight}
That way, the number of  rows in your table will be O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Then when your application reads the graph and perform some operation, you would have to build the graph in memory,and do the same.